# CKEditor with Typoscript or Marker

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typoscript

does anyone have an idea how I can add the username in ckeditor ? 
Whether with markers or with typoscript does not matter

thnx a lot

br

Comment: What is the "username" here? Can you add more details how you plan to use this afterwards?

Comment: similar {TSFE:fe_user|user|username} or ###username###

Comment: OK, that'd be the username of the current frontend user. Now what do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: I need user data in flowing text, editor should be able to edit  ... similar - Hello Max ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use markers like `{TSFE:fe_user|user|username}` inside both richtext editors of TYPO3, the new CKEditor as well as the old rtehtmlarea.

You would have to add this to your TypoScript setup:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.innerStdWrap_all.insertData = 1
```

**Caution!** Be aware that this would allow the editor to render the user's password, too!

The constants like `###marker###` (set in TypoScript setup, not the ones set in the constants section) only allow to use strings which unfortunately cannot be altered with `stdWrap` functions.

```
constants.EMAIL = info@example.org
```

**All** credits go to [Stefan Frömken's TYPO3 lexikon (german language)](https://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/core/systemextensions/rtehtmlarea/variablen-im-rte.html).